# Scale invariance

Tags: spacetime, quantum-gravity, discrete, scale-invariance

Physically why should scale invariance break down at the Planck limit? If not what are the other possibilities to save the quantum granularity of spacetime? I would really appreciate professional references.

Comment: Do you have any particular theory (or effective theory?) in mind which has scale invariance far below $M_{Pl}$?

Comment: @SRS Not really, I'm just wondering if there are any but not only scale invariant theories also with spacetime atoms. Is M-Theory so?